# asp.net mvc ViewBag и Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, кодировка

Добрый день! Исправленная версия (проблема была не во ViewBag)

Я пишу приложение на asp.net mvc, и у меня есть простое действие такого вида:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string cyrillicParam)
{
    // здесь параметр превращается вот в это: "�����������"
    // какой-то код
    return View();
}
```

Во всех браузерах всё работает как ожидалось. За исключением Internet Explorer. Там я в cyrillicParam получаю вот такое: "�����������"

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: <meta charset="utf-8"/>

Comment: @free_ze пробовал, не помогает

Comment: При данных симптомах ищите проблему на стороне исходного HTML и браузера. Кодировка файла, кодировка страницы, параметры формы, метод передачи, верстка(проверьте DOCTYPE) и т.д. Как правило в консоли разработчиков браузера можно узнать много интересного по самому запросу даже в IE. Ах да, еще укажите версии IE для которых симптомы сохраняются.

Answer (score 1):

ViewBag здесь не при чем. Введите `<h1>Мой текст</h1>`, чтобы убедиться.

Скорее всего проблема в кодировке файлов или в выбранной кодировке в браузере.

- Добавьте `<meta charset="utf-8" />` в head вашей страницы
- Убедитесь что файлы *.cshtml сохранены с кодировкой UTF-8 (VS обычно
  сохраняет их в UTF-8 с BOM)
- Убедитесь что в браузере выбрана кодировка страницы UTF-8 или автоматически, а не Windows-1251

Посмотреть кодировку можно, например, в Notepad++ (внизу окна справа). Для просмотра выбранной кодировки в браузере нажмите правой кнопкой в любое место страницы и выберите "Кодировка".

**Добавлено после обновления вопроса**

В этом случае на стороне клиента понадобится выполнить `encodeURI("Привет!");`. Эта функция вернет страшную строку `%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82!`, но она обработается корректно.

Comment: вы правы. проблема не во VuiewBag. Проблема в параметре url. Я обновил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста